# How to read and run a command 10 lines at a time in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that connects to servers via SSH to run a command. The script gets the IP address from a file.

Problem: if I have 500 IPs in the file, I don't want to simultaneously open or try to open 500 connections. I want to do, lets say, 10 at a time in order to save resources.

How do I run the command via SSH 10 servers at a time?

Here is my script:

```
#/bin/bash

nodes="big_list_of_nodes.txt"

while read node; do
   # Running in background
   (uptime=`ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 $node uptime 2>&1`
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "$node uptime: $uptime"
   else
      echo "Connection timeout for node $node"
   fi) &
 done < $nodes
 # Wait for all jobs to finish    
 wait
```

Comment: Keep a counter and add 10 IP's to an array. When the count reaches 10, make your connections, wait until they finish, unset the array, reset your count to 0, repeat.

Comment: Do you have [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) installed? (Or are you open to the idea of installing it?)

Answer (score 1):

You want to write a function to do all the work for you that takes an IP address as an argument. Then use `parallel` to read in the file and distribute work to the function:

```
function get_uptime() 
{
    node=$1

    uptime=`ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 $node uptime 2>&1`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "$node uptime: $uptime"
    else
       echo "Connection timeout for node $node"
    fi
}

export -f get_uptime

parallel -j 10 --will-cite -a big_list_of_nodes.txt get_uptime
```

The `-j` argument tells parallel how many jobs can be active at a time.

Comment: If you want to use parallel with a function, you have to export that function first.

Comment: What does the '--will-cite' option do?

Comment: It says you'll cite parallel as being used in your work: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Comment: The issue with that code is that the if statement no longer works. It probably needs to be out of the function, but I don't know how parallel with check for each connection (line in file).

Comment: There are other ways to run parallel without a shell function. I recommend the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: Another issue with that code is that is not executing 10 lines in the file and then the next 10 lines and so on. It is executing all of it (all lines).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99441/discussion-between-turn-and-greenteatech).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out and make it work.

I add N lines to an array, then I process everything in that array. Then the array is empty and the process is repeated.

This way, you can have a file with hundreds of hostnames or IP address and process in N chunks.

```
#/bin/bash

nodes=`cat big_list_of_nodes.txt`

for node in $nodes
 do
    array+=($node)
    if [ ${#array[@]} -gt 10 ]; then
      for n in ${array[@]}
       do
        (uptime=`ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 $n uptime 2>&1`
         if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "$n uptime: $uptime"
         else
            echo "Connection timeout for node $n"
         fi) &
       done
       wait
       array=()
    fi
 done

  if [ ${#array[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
     for n in ${array[@]}
       do
        (uptime=`ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 $n uptime 2>&1`
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
           echo "$n uptime: $uptime"
        else
           echo "Connection timeout for node $n"
        fi) &
      done
      wait
  fi
```